# Error: ".filter is not a function"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, vegetation-index

I'm trying to create a GUI on Google Earth Engine Javascript API to calculate vegetation indexes and plot them on a chart. I'm getting the error `l8.filter is not a function` in the line no. 316 where I've filtered the dates inside the function updateMap. I've done the basic debugging but couldn't fix it.

Here's the link to the whole program: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fshubhra29yadav%2Fndvi1%3AVertex

```
function updateMap() {
  var year = c.selectYear.slider.getValue();
  var band = c.selectBand.selector.getValue();
  var img = l8.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', parseInt(year10)))
            .select(m.imgInfo.bands[band].bname);
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(m.imgInfo.bands[band].vis,band + ',' + year);
  ui.Map.layers.set(0, layer);
}
```

Comment: Link to full code requires authentication/credentials I don't have, but where is `l8` defined?

Comment: Repository **users/shubhra29yadav/ndvi1** does not exist. Please, share it.